# Java empty block scope

Tags: java

I am wondering what's the purposes of using empty block. For example,

```
    static{
        int x = 5;
    }

    public static void main (String [] args){

          int i = 10;

          {
               int j = 0 ;
               System.out.println(x);  // compiler error : can't find x ?? why ??
               System.out.println(i);  // this is fine
          }
          System.out.println(j); //compiler error :  can't find j

    }
```

Can someone explains

1. In what situation that we would want to use empty block.
2. Are all the variables inside that empty block still goes on `stack` ?
3. Why couldn't it access the `static variable x` ?

Comment: `x` is declared in the scope of that static initializer. Similarly, `j` is declared in the scope of that inner block inside of `main`. You're attempting to resolve the symbols but they are not defined in those scopes.

Comment: so no one can access it except within that static block ?

Comment: Yes, indeed :-) You can read more on the scopes of declaration in [§6.3 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3).

Comment: By the way, as I said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024095/java-empty-block-scope/12024121#comment16046364_12024121), local variable allocation is implementation-specific and undefined in the VM specification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. The block that you are showing in your post is not an empty block, it is a static initializer. It is used to provide non-trivial initialization for static variables of your class
2. Local variables that you use during initialization go on stack, except for objects that you allocate from the heap
3. You cannot access static variable `x` because you did not declare it. Instead, you declared a local variable `x` inside a static initializer.

If you would like to make `x` a static variable and then initialize it in a static initialization block, do this:

```
private static int x;
static {
    x = 5;
}
```

In trivial cases like this, a straightforward initialization syntax works best:

```
private static int x = 5;
```

Initializer blocks are reserved for more complex work, for example, when you need to initialize structures using a loop:

```
private static List<List<String>> x = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
static {
    for (int i = 0 ; i != 10 ; i++) {
        x.add(new ArrayList<String>(20));
    }
}
```

Comment: I am wondering is it the same if you leave those operations in constructor instead of a static block ?

Comment: @user1389813 No, it is absolutely not the same: the constructor runs once per class *instance*, while static initializers, if any, run once per the entire class. This makes sense, because static fields are shared among all instances of a class, so their initialization needs to happen only once.

Comment: I see, then in what case do you want to use a static block inside a specific class that it will only execute once when the class is loaded ? can you give me an example ?

Comment: @user1389813 My answer shows a simple example of when this may be desirable (the code snippet at the bottom). Initializing a list of lists requires a loop, so one will either need to write a static function, or use a static initialization block.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Thanks Mike! I guess it shows that I have been programming in C# for too long :)

Comment: so if you declare a static block inside the main method. Does that mean anything ?

Comment: @user1389813 Static blocks are not declared inside methods, they are declared directly inside classes. Trying to do it inside methods [is a syntax error](http://ideone.com/sQDiY).

Comment: Sorry i meant an empty block (without static) inside a method

Comment: @user1389813 An empty block can appear as many times as you'd like, just as a semicolon (even like [this](http://ideone.com/yAsUu)). Compiler simply throws it away.

Comment: throws it away meaning ?　but then how come everything that you declare inside that empty block is not reachable like it's being a like a separate local scope

Comment: @user1389813 By "empty" I mean literally empty - that is, containing nothing inside (take a look at the link in my previous comment).

Comment: ok i really mean something like this { int y = 5; }  like empty block with statements inside

Comment: @user1389813 as far as free-standing non-empty blocks go, you can use them to hide variable declarations from the rest of the function. Here is a [link](http://ideone.com/6zWBy) to an example of declaring variables with the same name twice in the same function. You wouldn't be able to re-declare a variable without such blocks.

Comment: So it's just simply for hiding variables ? and i am wondering from your previous link seems like each block is kind of like a method where the variables go away as soon as the block finishes. Is that how it manages the memory ?

Comment: @user1389813 The memory management does not play into it at all, it is a way to hide a name. In my previous link the compiler is allowed to allocate the two x variables in different locations that exist at the same time, initialize them on entry to the enclosing method, and deallocate upon method's exit. It's just a mechanism for calling two different locations a single name.

Answer (score 4):

1. Anonymous code blocks are only useful to limit variable scope; they don't have any true purpose.
2. Yes, but the scope is limited to within that block.
3. The scope of x is limited to the static initialization block because it is declared within the method (static context is internally the  method), rather than within the static scope of the class.

Comment: so you are saying empty block inside a main method does not really mean anything ?

Comment: Empty blocks in any context don't really mean anything beyond a useless scope limitation.  In a class context, they allow for instance variable initialization, but it's far more conventional to use a constructor for that purpose.

Comment: I have used anonymous code blocks for structuring test code, slightly similar to C# regions. Misuse, yes, but more readable code in tests.

Answer (score 4):

Static blocks are useful to initialize static members since they run at class initialization time.

```
static final Map<K, V> MY_MAP = ...;

static {
  MY_MAP.put(...);
  ...
}
```

---

> Do all the variables inside that empty block still goes on stack ?

Variables declared in the static block are local variables, not static members of the class.  As @veer points out, whether it goes on the stack is a VM implementation detail.

---

> Why couldn't `main` access the static variable `x`?

Because it's a local variable that only exists for the duration of the `static` initializer.

Comment: Whether or not local variables are allocated on the stack is totally and completely VM dependent.

Comment: [§2.6 of the JVM Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6) states they are apart of VM frames, which are not explicitly stated to be allocated on the heap or the stack or _anywhere_.

Comment: @veer, the JVM is specified as a stack machine in that many bytecode instructions manipulate a stack instead of manipulating registers. That spec abstraction stack is the stack I'm referring to.

Comment: I'm afraid you're confused about [_operand stacks_ (§2.6.2)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.2)... local variables are not stored on the operand stack. They are stored in the [local variable table (§2.6.1)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1). ;-)

Comment: Nah, I didn't mean to correct you... merely clear things up :-) It's not your fault since the JVM is not *strictly* a stack machine as it's advertised to be... local variables are very much like registers.

Comment: @veer, Thanks.  It's important to use the right terminology when answering language lawyery questions.  Otherwise, people just get hopelessly lost when diving into large specs.