# What is the purpose of the {} outside of any methods?

Tags: java, initialization

I accidently made a pair of {} outside of all method and worked.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("ddd");
}

{
    System.out.println("ttt");
}
```

Of course if you run this code the result is "ddd" and it writes "ttt" only if I create a new instance of it.

And if I make it `static {System.out.println("ttt");}` it works as designed and the result is "ttt" then "ddd"

**Is there any practical use of this? Why would anyone use it with contructor or without a written constructor?**

My impressions are: it seems working, but smells like bad and strange practice. Am I right?

Comment: Possible answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024095/java-empty-block-scope

Comment: This code is added to the constructor. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865069/why-is-this-java-code-in-curly-braces-outside-of-a-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any practical use of this?

There is one "idiom" that makes use of instance initializer blocks:

```
 Map mymap = new HashMap() {{put("a", 1); put("b", 2);}};
```

This is a concise way to create a map that is initialized with a given set of entries.  And when you break it down, it is declaring and instantiating an anonymous subclass of `HashMap` which uses an instance initializer block to populate the new map.

---

> My impressions are: it seems working, but smells like bad and strange practice.

That's a subjective statement.  The only rational argument I can think of for initializer blocks being bad / strange is that people don't use them.  And that argument smells of circular logic.

Comment: I agree, it wouldn't really smelly if everybody would get used to it. But the reason I feel it smelly is that the code is a lot more clear if you make a private method and call it in constructors. You might miss this {} thing when you review some code and it is somewhere far from the constructors. At least I wouldn't suspect at the first time that something is called outside of the constructor. and the obvious static things. But I see the practical use of {{ blahblah }}

Answer (score 4):

`{}` define the scope of a module or block of code (like a method, static block, class, etc.)

And every module should have a name of something to identify it from other modules.

In your case, simply putting `{}` means you are creating a block of code but not naming, hence it gives error. But putting `{}` inside a method will work fine.

But when you put `static` keyword before it, you are making a static block that has got special meaning in java. it means that everything inside `static` block will be executed when your class gets loaded first time.

[See this link for initializer blocks from Java Tutorials website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Answer (score 2):

Its all about  [**Initializer blocks**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Initializer blocks for instance variables look just like static initializer blocks, but without the static keyword:

{

```
// will execute when intialization
```

}

The Java compiler copies initializer blocks into every constructor. Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between multiple constructors.

Comment: Yes, I just tried them, but is there any good practice use of it. For example, would you use it for anything? I would just use constructors and use private methods if it gets too fancy.

Comment: @CsBalazsHungary see updated answer.let me know still any lingering.

Answer (score 1):

These are called initializer blocks. They are called along with all constructor. So any constructor call will invoke this code.

A static block is called only when class is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you have to put the code to initialize an instance variable in a constructor. There are two alternatives to using a constructor to initialize instance variables: `initializer blocks` and `final methods`.

Initializer blocks for instance variables look just like static initializer blocks, but without the static keyword:

The `Java compiler` copies initializer blocks into every constructor. Therefore, this approach can be used to share a block of code between multiple constructors.

Source: [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

Answer (score 0):

It may be unfamiliar, but it is not bad per se. It's an initializer block that is executed on construction. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) for a more detailed explanation that includes static initialization blocks also.