# what does static initializer with no assignment mean?

Tags: java, static, initialization

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12024095/java-empty-block-scope)

> static initializer. It is used to provide non-trivial initialization
>   for static variables of your class

Then I saw this code:

```
public class CommandFactory {
    private CommandFactory() {
    }

    static {
        new CommandFactory();
    }
```

What's the purpose of it? (as there is no assignment to any field)

Comment: I assume the constructor lazily initialises some resources.

Comment: It's static initializer, executes when the class is loaded.

Comment: Where did you see this code?

Answer (score 3):

The author's intent might have been to instantiate `CommandFactory` for its constructor's [side-effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: But it's invoking an empty constructor, so what side effects are there?

Comment: Running instance initializers.

Comment: @Eran Maybe it's just for the example sake.

Answer (score 2):

This code doesn't make much sense. It is creating an instance using an empty constructor, so there are no side effects. And a reference to the created instance is not stored anywhere, so you can't even access it later.

It's possible this is a simplified example that is meant to explain some principle, but in this current form, it is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the context, this snippet makes no sense, except of feeding the garbage collector
But with  respect to the name `CommandFactory` and the private ctor it seems to be an inclomplete
singleton example and should may be look so:

```
public class CommandFactory {
    private static CommandFactory instance;

    private CommandFactory() {
    }

    static {
        instance = new CommandFactory();
    }

    public static CommandFactory getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

or so:

```
public class CommandFactory {
    private static CommandFactory instance = new CommandFactory();

    private CommandFactory() {
    }
    //...
}
```